# bank transaction activity - updating current balance after each transaction

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

i want to insert new value into table, by reading previous value of same attribute by using php mysql

```
transaction_id  deposit current_balance
   1              500      500
   2              300      800
```

if deposit 300 how the value of current_balance become 800.
    &
how to bank transaction activity perform

Answer (score 3):

Use a `SELECT` query to get the last balance, and add the deposit amount to that to get the new balance.

```
INSERT INTO transactions (deposit, current_balance)
SELECT :amount, current_balance + :amount
FROM transactions
ORDER BY transaction_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You can add more columns to this.

Comment: INSERT INTO transactions (deposit, current_balance, some)
SELECT :amount, current_balance + :amount, xyz
FROM transactions
ORDER BY transaction_id DESC
LIMIT 1    ...................this throwing an error

Comment: Mr. Barmar! could you tell me.......that what hardware and software is best to implement php mysql based application on local network.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know enough about hardware to make specific recommendations. But 600 records/day is really tiny, I expect practically any modern hardware would work. You probably don't need to worry until you get to hundreds of transactions per second.